# How to control multiple lines by finding one keyword in python?

Tags: python, html, file, while-loop, line

I am reading a python file and I want to find the line where there is a: " " " comment. After I find it I want the following lines from that python file to get some html code until the closing quotes " " " of the comment.

**Python file example:**

```
"""

Some comment in this area 

Another line with comment

Some more
More

"""

def main():
    var = something 
    file = somefile
    for i in x:
```

**The code that I tried but isn't really working:**

```
def main():
    file = open("pythonfile.py","r")
    infile = file.readlines()
    flag = False

    for line in infile:

        while len(line) > 0:

            if flag:
                index = line.find("\'\'\'")

                if index < 0:
                    print("<span style=\"color: green;\">",line[:],"</span>",end="")
                    flag = True
                    line = ""

                else:
                    print("<span style=\"color: green;\">",line[0:index+3],"</span>",end="")
                    flag = False
                    line = line[index+3:]
```

Where it says: if index < 0: I wanted that after the program finds the quotation marks all the following lines get the span color of green until it finds the closing quotation marks.

**The Output should look like this**

```
<span style=\"color: green;\">"""</span>

<span style=\"color: green;\">Some comment in this area </span>

<span style=\"color: green;\">Another line with comment</span>

<span style=\"color: green;\">Some more</span>
<span style=\"color: green;\">More</span>

<span style=\"color: green;\">"""</span>

def main():
    var = something 
    file = somefile
    for i in x:
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? Are you permanently changing those lines in the file? Are you going to display this in a web page?  Are you only interested in module [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) or any docstrings in the file?

Comment: I want the python code to be used in an HTML editor so the python keywords that have special color (for example:if, else, True,False,def etc. have the color yellow) get the HTML required to display those keywords.

Comment: No, I don't want to permanently change those lines, what I do is creating a file that is adding all the python code with the HTML code to it, so I am just reading the python file and adjust it and send the adjusted code to a NEW file.

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open("pythonfile.py" ,"r")
infile = file.readlines()
flag = False
# headop = True

for line in infile:
    line2=line
    if line[-1]=='\n':
        line2=line[:-1]
    index=line2.find("\"\"\"")
    if index>=0:
        index2 = line2[index+3:].find("\"\"\"")
        if index2>=0:
            index2+=(index+3)
    else:
        index2=-1
    if index<0:
        if flag:
            print("<span style=\"color: green;\">" ,line2 ,"</span>", sep="")
        else:
            print(line2)
    else:
        if flag:
            print("<span style=\"color: green;\">" ,line2[0:index+3] ,"</span>", end="", sep="")
            if index2<0:
                print(line2[index+3:])
                flag=False
            else:
                print(line2[index+3:index2], end="")
                print("<span style=\"color: green;\">" ,line2[index2:] ,"</span>", sep="")
                flag=True
        else:
            print(line2[0:index], end="")
            if index2<0:
                print("<span style=\"color: green;\">" ,line2[index:] ,"</span>", sep="")
                flag=True
            else:
                print("<span style=\"color: green;\">" ,line2[index:index2+3] ,"</span>", end="", sep="")
                print(line2[index2+3:])
                flag=False
```

output is

```
<span style="color: green;">"""</span>
<span style="color: green;"></span>
<span style="color: green;">Some comment in this area</span>
<span style="color: green;"></span>
<span style="color: green;">Another line with comment</span>
<span style="color: green;"></span>
<span style="color: green;">Some more</span>
<span style="color: green;">More</span>
<span style="color: green;"></span>
<span style="color: green;">"""</span>

def main():
    <span style="color: green;">""" this is a test</span>
<span style="color: green;">     in code block """</span>
    var = 'something'
    var2 = <span style="color: green;">"""different"""</span>
    var3 = <span style="color: green;">"""diff1"""</span>
    file = 'somefile'
    for i in range(10):
        print("i=",i)
    str = <span style="color: green;">""" this is a test</span>
<span style="color: green;">            and test and test. """</span>
    print("str=",str)

<span style="color: green;">""" call main() """</span>
main()
```

Comment: I figured it out right after you commented the answer! I really  appreciate that you tried to help me out!!